# Swift iOS Project Leaks As Soon As An Empty Project Is Created

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I've seen a fair bit of noise about "false positives," and have even encountered them, myself.

However, this takes the cake.

Easy to reproduce, using Swift 5/Xcode 10.2, create a new single-view iOS app.

Run Leaks.

You get these critters:

```
Malloc 64 Bytes 1   0x600001d084c0  64 Bytes    Foundation  +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]
Malloc 16 Bytes 3   < multiple >    48 Bytes         
Malloc 1.50 KiB 3   < multiple >    4.50 KiB         
Malloc 32 Bytes 3   < multiple >    96 Bytes         
Malloc 8.00 KiB 1   0x7fc56f000c00  8.00 KiB         
Malloc 64 Bytes 10  < multiple >    640 Bytes        
Malloc 80 Bytes 3   < multiple >    240 Bytes        
Malloc 4.00 KiB 3   < multiple >    12.00 KiB
```

Using the simulator (XR, iOS 12.2).

That first one has a stack trace, but it's worthless.

Is there some way that I can correct for this noise? I'm writing an infrastructure component, and I need to:

A) Make damn sure it doesn't leak, and

B) Not have every Cocoapod jockey on Earth emailing me, and telling me that my component leaks.

Comment: I know one way to use 12.1 simulator

Comment: I’ll try that out.

Comment: That would explain some inconsistencies, as this did not happen in earlier testing.

Comment: @E.Coms: OK. Looks like it's an issue with the new ABI. If you phrase your comment as an answer, I'll greencheck you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using a iOS 12.1 simulator , the `leak` instrument still can work (Swift 5/Xcode 10.2). Currently we are hoping it will be fixed in future versions.

Comment: Thanks! I sent in a bug report to Apple.