# Why does a single view swift application with no code leak memory?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, profiling

I created a single view swift application with a `UILabel` on it.

When I try to profile this application, it seems to be leaking memory. Why does this happen?

[image: Screenshot with leaked memory]

I am sure, I am missing a step or a flag somewhere but I am unable to find it.

I haven't written any code of my own in this application. It's an app created with XCode iOS Single View App template. Could someone please help me understand what's going on here?

### Edit 1:

Here is the code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
}
```

Also attaching the screenshot of the Main storyboard.
[image: Screenshot of Main storyboard]

Comment: You said there is a `UILabel` in the application. Therefore it is not a blank application. Please share relevant code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift iOS Project Leaks As Soon As An Empty Project Is Created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524125/swift-ios-project-leaks-as-soon-as-an-empty-project-is-created)

Comment: @BhavikModi I am running the app on actual device. I tried it on the iPad and an iPhone XR both on iOS 12.3.1. On both the device, I get similar result. I will try to profile it on the Simulator 12.1 and report back

Comment: @BhavikModi Yes, it doesn't show the leak on iOS 12.1 simulator. I would have loved if Apple fixed this issue even in the newer version of iOS. Thanks for the tip. This is however a problem for us, our real app uses camera feature and its a pain to profile it on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you have no code in your application, logically there shouldn't be
>   any memory leak .

With that cleared up lets talk about instruments **(the green checks and the red x marks)**, they usually indicates a change in the memory usage doesn't always mean there is a memory leak, this could be many caused by many reasons.

as you can see the checking is done every timestamp, so it compares the memory usage between those timestamps and decide if there is any potential memory leak, those jumps in memory are not always justified with a memory, but more like there was a change in the memory during this timestamp, so you can check it out, if it was a memory leak indeed or just normal memory going up due to some functionalities  or depended objects being allocated, it is a monitoring tool more than a detecting  errors tool, that is used to monitor the changes of our application memory allocations etc ..

Comment: I am going to mark this as the accepted answer, since the question is Why does the application leak memory? For other who are wondering how to profile the application to detect memory leaks, please use the Debug Memory Graph feature of XCode. Follow [here](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/ios-identifying-memory-leaks-using-the-xcode-memory-graph-debugger-e84f097b9d15) and [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-visual-memory-debugger/)